# Blocked Cross Origin Spring Boot And React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, fetch-api

I am working on a project in react and spring boot, and I got issue with the cross origin from my spring server, I put the crossOrogin annotation on my controller and is not working me I tried many ways (from spring official web) non of them worked to me. Is anyone can help me please with that I really don’t know what to do. Here is my [controller](https://github.com/sharas36/SpringBootProject/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springCoupon/controllers/CustomerController.java) , ;
},

And this is my error with react:
[error image for react uskg chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2i8w.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
 @Configuration
public class CrossConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOriginPatterns("*") // SpringBoot2.4.0 [allowedOriginPatterns]replace[allowedOrigins]
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .maxAge(3600)
            .allowCredentials(true);
}}
```

Comment: code block miss a bracket